# Can adverbs be connected with noun by の particle?

Tags: grammar, particle-の

> oshirase
>
> 今日は日本の授業がありません
>
> 私の女の子が熱が痛いですから... 学生たちのほかに調べてくださいね...お願いします...明日宿題は学校の後でSMP Regularの事務所でMr.Jayに取ってください. 月曜日Mr.Jayに出してください.

後で and 他に are adverbs in my dictionary. My teacher sent me this message which contain phrases of  "noun + の + adverbs". In this case does the の still mean "of"? Btw the part where she told me that her daughter is sick seems wrong. 熱が痛い??! Is it not 熱があります?! And I don't understand the 学生たちのほかに調べてくださいね part.

Comment: 「学生達のほかに調べてください」 doesn't make much sense... What's the context? (「学校の後」「学生達のほか」 are "noun + の + noun", btw.)

Comment: Even with the context, 学生たちのほかに調べてください makes little sense.　I am afraid to say this but the whole passage sounds quite awkward with several grammar errors such as 日本の授業→日本語の授業、私の女の子→娘、熱が痛い→熱がある・熱が高い・頭が痛い、Mr.Jayに取ってください→Mr.J‌​ayに/からもらってください・Mr.Ja‌​yから受け取ってください

Comment: I agree, thankyou for pointing it out.

Comment: Is this your teachre's e-mail message in Japanese? The problem is your Japanese teacher is not qualified teacher at all!

Answer (score 1):

"学校の後で" is not as "noun+の+adverb". It is "noun+の+noun" forming an adverb clause.

"学生達のほかに調べてください" is indeed a bit odd sentence, because "学生たちのほかに" is not an adverb clause and needs a noun or noun clause to follow. My guess is that that is omitted here. It could be something like "学生たちのほかに（知人を）調べてください".